# What happened at the night of the Wythburn Mill operation?

Tags: lockwood-and-co

> The light went out.
>
> Then all the screams began.
>
> I twisted my head, looked back down the passage and across the foyer
>   towards the open door. Far off in the distant dusk I saw the
>   cigarette’s pinprick point of red.
>
> ‘Sir! Mr Jacobs!’
>
> Nothing.
>
> ‘Sir! We need your help! Sir!’
>
> The pinprick flared as the agent took a breath. No answer came. He
>   didn’t move. Then wind roared along the corridor and nearly knocked me
>   off my feet. The walls of the mill shook; the open door slammed shut.
>
> I cursed in the darkness. Then I drew a canister from my belt, raised
>   my rapier high, and ran round the corner of the corridor towards the
>   screams. *~Jonathan Stroud: The Screaming Staircase, ch 5*

Here Lucy's account stops. We only know that all her fellow agents, who entered the house, died that night.

Does she mention later what exactly happened that night, how Lucy dealt with the visitor?